# Не могу обратиться к неймспейсу проекта

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-6

Всем привет! Изучаю сейчас книгу по ASP NET. Начал выполнять пример и столкнулся с ошибкой. Пытаюсь создать файл с импортом представлений, в нем прописываю нужный неймспейс, но выдается ошибка. Уточню, что неймспейс самого проекта, не какой то сторонней библиотеки. Помогите пожалуйста :([image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Program.cs**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.Run();
```

Comment: А покажите `Program.cs`

Comment: 3 скрин показывает название проекта, но н доказывает, что неймспейс существует. Откройте `Program.cs`, посмотрите, а есть ли он там.

Comment: @aepot добавил скришот

Comment: на самой верхней строчке Program.cs напишите `namespace WebApplication1;` и пересоберите проект.

Comment: @aepot ваше решение не работает. Нейспейс хоть и добавился, но я все равно не могу обращаться к папке Models. Так в добавок сам файл Programm.cs весь в ошибках.

Comment: Так создайте что-нибудь в папке Models, напишите там `namespace WebApplication1.Models;`, нельзя обратиться к тому, чего нет. Папка - это не неймспейс, неймспейсы в файлах с кодом прописываются.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы создать неймпейс `WebApplication1`, приведите **Program.cs** к такому виду

```
namespace WebApplication1;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        var app = builder.Build();

        app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

        app.Run();
    }
}
```

Далее добавьте что-нибудь в папку **Models**, например класс **Model1.cs**

```
namespace WebApplication1.Models;

public class Model1
{

}
```

Теперь вы сможете использовать неймспейс в Razor View

```
@using WebApplication1.Models;
```